About the dual of an ideal with respect to trace
I am studying about different ideal of a number field $K$, and I encountered the definition of dual of an ideal. It has been defined by
$$\hat{\mathfrak{b}}= \{x \in K : Tr(xb) \in \mathbb{Z} \text{ for all } b \in \mathfrak{b}\}$$
1- Is it true that $$\widehat{\mathfrak{b}_1 \mathfrak{b}_2}=\hat{\mathfrak{b}_1}\hat{\mathfrak{b_2}}$$ for two integral ideals
$\mathfrak{b}_1$ and $\mathfrak{b}_1$. If not is this true under some assumption for example $\mathfrak{b}_1$ and $\mathfrak{b}_2$ are coprime integral ideals? I used the definition of dual of an ideal, but cannot proceed further.
That is I assumed that $x$ and $y$ lie inside $\mathfrak{b}_1$ and $\mathfrak{b}_2$ respectively, now I wanted to prove that $xy$ lies in $\widehat{\mathfrak{b}_1 \mathfrak{b}_2}$. Thus I wanted to prove that $Tr(xyz) \subset \mathbb{Z} \text{ for all } z \in \mathfrak{b}_1 \mathfrak{b}_2$. For simplicity I am assuming $z=b_1 b_2$ since trace is linear, and thus I am left with $Tr(xyb_1 b_2)=Tr((xb_1)(y b_2))$. Now I have no idea what can I do here.

Did you try to find any actual examples at all when $K \not= \mathbf Q$, even in the case of quadratic fields?  I suspect you didn't.  It turns out they don't exist when $K \not= \mathbf Q$.
When $K$ is any number field and $\mathfrak b$ is any fractional ideal in $K$, it turns out that $\widehat{\mathfrak b} = \mathfrak b^{-1}\widehat{\mathcal O_K}$: see Theorem 3.9 here.  Since we define the different ideal to be $\mathcal D_K = \widehat{\mathcal O_K}^{-1}$, we have
$$
\widehat{\mathfrak b} = {\mathfrak b}^{-1}\mathcal D_K^{-1}.
$$
(Maybe this formula is good enough for whatever you want to do.)
Thus the desired equation
$\widehat{\mathfrak b_1}\widehat{\mathfrak b_2} = \widehat{\mathfrak b_1\mathfrak b_2}$ is equivalent to saying ${\mathcal D}_K{\mathcal D}_K = {\mathcal D}_K$, which is equivalent to ${\mathcal D}_K = \mathcal O_K$, and that last equation is never true when $K \not= \mathbf Q$ since ${\rm N}(\mathcal D_K) = |{\rm disc}(K)| > 1$.
